# Css not loading in production mode when using nextjs

Tags: css, webpack, sass, next.js, webpack-style-loader

## Problem

When building and starting a production build of our application, no *css* is loaded. CHecking the devtools, I can see a myriad of errors and warnings:

[image: Screenshot of errors and warnings in the console]

## Possible Culprits

I do not experience any of these problems, when starting the app in dev mode. Also, other assets like images or fonts are loaded correctly. We use *scss* and import the global stylesheet in **_app.tsx** like this:

```
import "../styles/globals.scss";
```

In order to solve a problem with another library, we had to setup a custom webpack config:

```
module.exports = phase => ({
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.node$/,
      use: "node-loader"
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            experimentalWatchApi: true,
            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true
          }
        }
      ],
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@private/")],
      exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@private/src/styleguide")]
    });

    if (!isServer) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          {
            loader: "resolve-url-loader",
            options: { removeCR: true, debug: true }
          },
          { loader: "sass-loader" }
        ]
      });
    }

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            exclude: /node_modules/
          }
        }
      ],
      exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@private/src")]
    });

    return config;
  }
});
```

Also, we this is the file of the custom server we use to start the application in production mode:

```
const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3364;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));

  server.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(` => Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

## Assumptions

As the custom server is the only difference between production and development, I can only assume that the error is maybe somewhere there. But it looks fine to me. So if anybody has a hint or an idea, I would be very grateful.

Comment: what is the value of isServer ?

Comment: @AmareshSM From the docs: "The webpack function is executed twice, once for the server and once for the client. This allows you to distinguish between client and server configuration using the `isServer` property".

Comment: so you are not using style-loader,css-loader in production mode?

Comment: @AmareshSM, no I don't use it on the server. I just tried to remove it and got the error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I just deleted the *.next* folder prior to building the production version via `npm run build` and after that, everything worked. Seems like there is some problems with the chunk generation when the .next folder is there.

Comment: It really works. I also got that css not loading problem when ```next build```. You saved my life.

Comment: Also my issue in 2023. Nearly 2024 :)